# Solving set of two quadratic equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Hi I am trying to simultaneously solve these two equations (it is a chemistry problem but I tried to write in in pure mathematical terms):

$$a_1x + a_2xy + 2a_3x^2y + a_4xy^2+a_5 = 0$$

$$a_1x + a_2xy + 2a_3x^2y + 2a_4xy^2+a_6 = 0$$

I am to be honest stuck in terms of how to solve for $x$ (or $y$) without ending up with the opposite variable $y$ (or $x$) in that in solution. I am sure there some trick I am missing here to simplify this? Or can one only solve this sort of problem using the method of successive approximation? Apologies if there is an answer somewhere already but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Subtract the two, and almost everything cancels out. Solve for $x\,$ in tems of $y\,$, then substitute back in either of the original equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you use one of the equations and solve for $x$ or $y$ and *accept* that the solution is in terms of the other variable.  That is *supposed* to happen.  Then take those two solutions and put them into the othe equation and solve.

Example:

$a_1x + a_2xy + 2a_3x^2y + a_4xy^2+a_5 = 0$

$(2a_3y)x^2 + (a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2)x + a_5 = 0$

$x = \frac {-(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2) \pm \sqrt {(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2)^2 - 4(2a_3y)a_5}}{2(2a_3y)}$

So plug that into:

$a_1\frac {-(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2) \pm \sqrt {(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2)^2 - 4(2a_3y)a_5}}{2(2a_3y)} + a_2\frac {-(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2) \pm \sqrt {(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2)^2 - 4(2a_3y)a_5}}{2(2a_3y)}y + 2a_3(\frac {-(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2) \pm \sqrt {(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2)^2 - 4(2a_3y)a_5}}{2(2a_3y)})^2y + 2a_4(\frac {-(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2) \pm \sqrt {(a_1 + a_2y + a_4y^2)^2 - 4(2a_3y)a_5}}{2(2a_3y)})y^2+a_6 = 0$

And solve for $y$.

But in this case we can make it easier.

$a_1x + a_2xy + 2a_3x^2y + a_4xy^2+a_5 = 0$

$a_1x + a_2xy + 2a_3x^2y + 2a_4xy^2+a_6 = 0$ so subtract and get

$a_4xy^2 + a_6 - a_5 = 0$

$a_4xy^2 = a_5- a_6$ so

$a_1x + a_2xy + 2a_3x^2y + 2a_5 - a_6 = 0$

And $y = \pm \sqrt{\frac {a_5-a_6}{a_4x}}$

So $a_1x + a_2x(\pm \sqrt{\frac {a_5-a_6}{a_4x}}) + 2a_3x^2(\pm \sqrt{\frac {a_5-a_6}{a_4x}}) + 2a_5 - a_6 = 0$

Solve for that to get $x$.

Comment: Thanks! So in general for two quadratics, if things wouldn't fall so nicely in place when you can subtract one from another (like in my specific lucky case), you would have to solve for _x_ first and plug the quadratic solution for x into the second equation to obtain _y_  like you did at the start of your answer? To me that means if this was a numerical problem (e.g., to work out the concentration of two chemicals _x_ and _y_) we can't really work out them out unless we know either _x_ or _y_? That is, there is no magical simultaneous solution?

Comment: No, if the two equations are true and the equations are independent there will be 4 possible solutions.  SOlve one in terms of one variable in terms of the (you will get two solutions) plug those into the second equation and you will get two equations each with only one variable. Solve those.  That'll give you for possible simultanious solutions.  But you can combine any linear combination of the equations to get a third simpler one if that makes things easier.

Comment: Thanks again! I suspected as much - good to have it confirmed. There is no such thing as free lunch.

Comment: @fleablood: I think Palli misunderstood your comment. He first remarked, "_...we can't really work them out unless we know either x or y_". Then he answered, "_I suspected as much - good to have it confirmed_". If he knew CAS like _Mathematica_ can eliminate $y$ between $F_1(x,y),\;F_2(x,y)$ using resultants yielding a quartic in $x$, then he can "magically" solve for $x$ using only his given coefficients, _without knowing the solution for y_. I wonder what he concluded in his chemistry research.

Comment: I'm not sure how many ways one can misunderstand the comment "No".  Of course maybe I misunderstood his comment of "simultaneously solve".